# Make AngularJs crawlable for search engines

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-crawler, search-engine

I am a noob with angular, and making javascript crawlable. I've been searching for it, but I don't really get it so far.

I am working on a AngularJs thingie which is using client-side JSON.
There is a navigation with pages, but... each link is using a function getPage(n) to slice a chunk of JSON and Angular renders it.

Is it OK to put a href="#!page=n" to each link? When I add that hash #! to the url and press enter, and a function renders the right items, is that enough to make it crawlable?

I've read something about snapshots, but it requires Java? I have a webhost which is not really flexible, it does **NOT** TomCat or NodeJs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's much better practice these days to use HTML5 `history.pushState`, and thus provide a unique URL for every page.

[More information here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Answer (score 1):

Check this older stackoverflow question - [Making angular crawlable - Beginning of Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771488/making-angular-crawlable-beginning-of-project)

A friend of mine uses - https://prerender.io/

Both these solutions are essentially caching versions of your rendered views, so the crawler can index your site.